# Parse XML data in SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, parsing

I was studing a little about xml parsing, using examples I found here in stackoverflow but I came across a doubt.
If I have something like this

```
DECLARE @xml xml
SET @xml = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<oo_outbound_order>   
         <oo_master>
              <Code>123</Code>
              <Name>Branan</Name> 
         </oo_master> 
    </oo_outbound_order>'

SELECT 
    n.value('(./Code/text())[1]','int') as CODE
 , n.value('(./Name/text())[1]','Varchar(50)') as NAME
FROM @xml.nodes('/oo_outbound_order/oo_master') as a(n)
```

I get something like this

```
CODE    NAME
123     Branan
```

but if one of the fields I want to store it as xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<oo_outbound_order> 
        <Active>true</Active>
        <Weight>0.02</Weight>
         <oo_master>
              <Code>123</Code>
              <Name>Branan</Name> 
        </oo_master>
    </oo_outbound_order>
```

And I want to get something like this

```
 Active   Weight    ColWithXML
  true     0.02     <oo_master><Code>123</Code><Name>Branan</Name></oo_master>


SELECT 
    n.value('Active[1][not(@xsi:nil = "true")]', 'BIT') as Active
 , n.value('Weight[1][not(@xsi:nil = "true")]', 'DECIMAL(29,5)') as Weight
, ??????????????????
```

How can I do that? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer was provided in the comments my [lptr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12403612/lptr), and it answered the OP's question. To preserve the usefulness of the comments, as they can be deleted at any time, I have posted it as an answer.

Here they (lptr) uses the `query` method of the `xml` data type ([query() Method (xml Data Type)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/query-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15)) to achieve your goal. They used 2 different, but similar similar solutions:

> `a.n.query('.')`
>
> ```sql
> DECLARE @xml xml
> SET @xml = 
> '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
> <oo_outbound_order>   
>          <oo_master>
>               <Code>123</Code>
>               <Name>Branan</Name> 
>          </oo_master> 
>     </oo_outbound_order>'
>
> SELECT 
>     n.value('(./Code/text())[1]','int') as CODE
>  , n.value('(./Name/text())[1]','Varchar(50)') as NAME
>  ,a.n.query('.')
> FROM @xml.nodes('/oo_outbound_order/oo_master') as a(n)
> ```
>
> [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=771a64e67ae7a973a65a182c65d3077b)

> ..or `n.query('oo_master') FROM @xml.nodes('/oo_outbound_order')`
>
> ```sql
> DECLARE @xml xml
> SET @xml = 
> '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
> <oo_outbound_order>   
>          <oo_master>
>               <Code>123</Code>
>               <Name>Branan</Name> 
>          </oo_master> 
>     </oo_outbound_order>'
>
> SELECT 
>     n.value('(./Code/text())[1]','int') as CODE
>  , n.value('(./Name/text())[1]','Varchar(50)') as NAME
>  ,a.n.query('.')
> FROM @xml.nodes('/oo_outbound_order/oo_master') as a(n);
>
>
> select @xml ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
> <oo_outbound_order> 
>         <Active>true</Active>
>         <Weight>0.02</Weight>
>          <oo_master>
>               <Code>123</Code>
>               <Name>Branan</Name> 
>         </oo_master>
>     </oo_outbound_order>';
>   
> SELECT 
> n.value('Active[1][not(@xsi:nil = "true")]', 'BIT') as Active
>  , n.value('Weight[1][not(@xsi:nil = "true")]', 'DECIMAL(29,5)') as Weight
>  , a.n.query('./oo_master')
> FROM @xml.nodes('/oo_outbound_order') as a(n);
> ```
>
> [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3a499d814aba001b4bbd15bec42ed6cb)